# How to pass subscribed value to another Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem to pass a subscribed value to another component.

**Structur:**

```
app/
---elements/
------navigation.component.ts
---pages/
------login/
----------login.component.ts
```

**login.component.ts**

```
isAuthenticated: any = false;

  onSignin() {
    this.authService.signinUser(this.myForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.isAuthenticated = data;
        });
  }
```

`this.isAuthenticated` is true if the login was successful.

What is the best way to send the data of **isAuthenticated** to the **navigation.component.ts**?

**navigation.component.ts**

```
isAuthenticated: any = false;

  constructor (private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.isAuthenticated = data;
      });
  }
```

Added:
**auth.service.ts**

```
isAuthenticated() {

      if (this.currentUser != null) {

        const token = this.currentUser.token;

        const body = JSON.stringify({token: token});
        return this.http.post('https://test.com/src/v13n22214', body)
          .map((response: Response) => {
            const authResponse = response.json().response;
            if (authResponse) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          });
      }
```

Comment: I think this might help you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463343/get-the-value-returned-by-canactivate-method-in-angular2-route-in-a-component/41467816#41467816

Answer (score 0):

You should save the value in the service then you can get it in another component, since you already injected the service

```
 constructor (private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
 }
```

Comment: You mean to save it in a variable? I added the function in my answer