# Angular 2 - service call inside canActivate

Tags: angular

Using guards, I try to access a service

but I cant return a promise in canActivate (which has particular signature that I cannot change)

my autService returns a promise since it is asynchrone

how can I achieve something similar :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;

        this.authService.canAccessUrl(url)
        .then( (answer:boolean) => {return answer;} );

    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: You know canActivate can return `Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean`. What do you mean by "signature that I cannot change" ?

Comment: take a look at this answer by me hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463343/get-the-value-returned-by-canactivate-method-in-angular2-route-in-a-component/41467816#41467816

Comment: ok , why dont they talk about this in the doc....

Comment: @Rahul Singh it does not answer the question

Comment: @echonax do you have any example, cos so far the only one I found use :boolean

Comment: @ninja I don't know where you are looking for examples.. It's in the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the signature of **canActivate**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    let url: string = state.url;

    this.authService.canAccessUrl(url)
    .then( (answer:boolean) => {return answer;} );

   }
}
```

Please check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html